# Wallpaper on Android: Automatically update to latest Instagram post

Tags: wallpaper, instagram

I'd like to automatically update my Android wallpaper when a new image appears on a target Instagram account (not my own). Running once a day is fine.

What I've tried: IFTTT recipe tied to custom FetchRSS feed...but it seems the recipe fails to extract the image URL from the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to URL:
https://web.stagram.com/rss/n/{INSTAGRAM_USERNAME}
For example, https://web.stagram.com/rss/n/puuung1

Verify a RSS feed appears.

Create the IFTTT recipe:
This: "RSS Feed" > New feed item, then enter the RSS feed URL from above
That: Android Device > Update device wallpaper > EntryImageUrl

NOTES

- It seems this may not update your wallpaper until a new feed item appears
- It seems any RSS feed errors may cause the update to fail...you can run through a validator to confirm (e.g., the FetchRSS feed had an error)
- The wallpaper may not be resized properly if a video or other non-image media